# Multilayered array in database, can't push array into second layer

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, push, database

In my database i have the following setup for testdata:

```
test1  [

   [0] { test: Array, comments: Array },
   [1] { test: Array, comments: Array }

]
```

Below is how i define the userSchema, it contains more but i think they are irrelevant in this scenario.

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({

    test1: { type: Array, required: false },
    test2: { type: Array, required: false },
    test3: { type: Array, required: false }

});
```

Below is a part of the code that saves the data to the database. The "newTest1" is an array of comments. I've been trying to add a comment to the object but have been unable to. The idea is that i first add the data which creates the object (see api.js below) and then add the comments.

No error is displayed, the array I'm trying to get into the object is just not added. In the api.js (code snippet further down) I'm able to push into the first layer of the array but not the object within. This must mean that i can't see into the array from the database but i don't know why this is. I think if i somehow could get the array from the database, add the comments then user.save it would work but i don't know how to do that or if that is the best solution. Could someone help me out?

html:

```
  <form name="edit.test1" ng-submit="ctrl.updateTest1(newComment1, newComment2, ctrl.artikel)">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Kommentarer:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="test1" placeholder="Comment on first value" ng-model="newComment1" autocomplete="off">
        <br>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="test1" placeholder="Comment on second value" ng-model="newComment2" autocomplete="off">
    </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

  </form>
```

Controller:

```
app.updateTest1 = function(newComment1, newComment2, index) {
          app.errorMsg = false; // Clear any error message
          app.disabled = true; // Lock form while processing
          // Check if username submitted is valid

              var userObject = {}; // Create the user object to pass to function
              userObject._id = app.currentUser; // Pass current user _id in order to edit

              userObject.test1 = [$scope.newComment1, $scope.newComment2, index]; // Set the new username provided

              // Runs function to update the user's username
              User.editUser(userObject).then(function(data) {

                // Behöver jag lägga till något här??

              });
            };
```

Userfactory:

```
  userFactory.editUser = function(id) {
        return $http.put('/api/edit', id);
    };
```

Creating a new user when a user registers:

```
router.post('/users', function(req, res) {
        var user = new User(); // Create new User object
        user.username = req.body.username; // Save username from request to User object
        user.password = req.body.password; // Save password from request to User object
        user.email = req.body.email; // Save email from request to User object
        user.name = req.body.name; // Save name from request to User object
        user.temporarytoken = jwt.sign({ username: user.username, email: user.email }, secret, { expiresIn: '24h' }); // Create a token for activating account through e-mail

        // Check if request is valid and not empty or null
        if (req.body.username === null || req.body.username === '' || req.body.password === null || req.body.password === '' || req.body.email === null || req.body.email === '' || req.body.name === null || req.body.name === '') {
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'Ensure username, email, and password were provided' });
        } else {
            // Save new user to database
            user.save(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    // Check if any validation errors exists (from user model)
                    if (err.errors !== null) {
                        if (err.errors.name) {
                            res.json({ success: false, message: err.errors.name.message }); // Display error in validation (name)
                        } else if (err.errors.email) {
                            res.json({ success: false, message: err.errors.email.message }); // Display error in validation (email)
                        } else if (err.errors.username) {
                            res.json({ success: false, message: err.errors.username.message }); // Display error in validation (username)
                        } else if (err.errors.password) {
                            res.json({ success: false, message: err.errors.password.message }); // Display error in validation (password)
                        } else {
                            res.json({ success: false, message: err }); // Display any other errors with validation
                        }
                    } else if (err) {
                        // Check if duplication error exists
                        if (err.code == 11000) {
                            if (err.errmsg[61] == "u") {
                                res.json({ success: false, message: 'That username is already taken' }); // Display error if username already taken
                            } else if (err.errmsg[61] == "e") {
                                res.json({ success: false, message: 'That e-mail is already taken' }); // Display error if e-mail already taken
                            }
                        } else {
                            res.json({ success: false, message: err }); // Display any other error
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // Create e-mail object to send to user
                    var email = {
                        from: 'MEAN Stack Staff, cruiserweights@zoho.com',
                        to: [user.email, 'gugui3z24@gmail.com'],
                        subject: 'Your Activation Link',
                        text: 'Hello ' + user.name + ', thank you for registering at localhost.com. Please click on the following link to complete your activation: http://www.herokutestapp3z24.com/activate/' + user.temporarytoken,
                        html: 'Hello<strong> ' + user.name + '</strong>,<br><br>Thank you for registering at localhost.com. Please click on the link below to complete your activation:<br><br><a href="http://www.herokutestapp3z24.com/activate/' + user.temporarytoken + '">http://www.herokutestapp3z24.com/activate/</a>'
                    };
                    // Function to send e-mail to the user
                    client.sendMail(email, function(err, info) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err); // If error with sending e-mail, log to console/terminal
                        } else {
                            console.log(info); // Log success message to console if sent
                            console.log(user.email); // Display e-mail that it was sent to
                        }
                    });
                    res.json({ success: true, message: 'Account registered! Please check your e-mail for activation link.' }); // Send success message back to controller/request
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

api.js:

```
    router.put('/edit', function(req, res) {
            var editUser = req.body._id; // Assign _id from user to be editted to a variable
            if (req.body.name) var newName = req.body.name; // Check if a change to name was requested
            if (req.body.username) var newUsername = req.body.username; // Check if a change to username was requested
            if (req.body.email) var newEmail = req.body.email; // Check if a change to e-mail was requested
            if (req.body.permission) var newPermission = req.body.permission; // Check if a change to permission was requested

            if (req.body.test1) {
              var newTest1 = req.body.test1;
            }
            if (req.body.test2) {
              var newTest2 = req.body.test2;
            }
            if (req.body.test3) {
              var newTest3 = req.body.test3;
            }
            if (req.body.test4) {
              var newTest4 = req.body.test4;
            }
            if (req.body.test5) {
              var newTest5 = req.body.test5;
            }


            // Look for logged in user in database to check if have appropriate access
            User.findOne({ username: req.decoded.username }, function(err, mainUser) {
                if (err) {
                    // Create an e-mail object that contains the error. Set to automatically send it to myself for troubleshooting.
                    var email = {
                        from: 'MEAN Stack Staff, cruiserweights@zoho.com',
                        to: 'gugui3z24@gmail.com',
                        subject: 'Error Logged',
                        text: 'The following error has been reported in the MEAN Stack Application: ' + err,
                        html: 'The following error has been reported in the MEAN Stack Application:<br><br>' + err
                    };
                    // Function to send e-mail to myself
                    client.sendMail(email, function(err, info) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err); // If error with sending e-mail, log to console/terminal
                        } else {
                            console.log(info); // Log success message to console if sent
                            console.log(user.email); // Display e-mail that it was sent to
                        }
                    });
                    res.json({ success: false, message: 'Something went wrong. This error has been logged and will be addressed by our staff. We apologize for this inconvenience!' });
                } else {
                    // Check if logged in user is found in database
                    if (!mainUser) {
                        res.json({ success: false, message: "no user found" }); // Return error
                    } else {
                        // Check if a change to name was requested

-----> HERE               if (newTest1) {
                          // Check if person making changes has appropriate access
                          if (mainUser.permission === 'admin') {
                              // Look for user in database
                              User.findOne({ _id: editUser }, function(err, user) {
                                  if (err) {
                                      res.json({ success: false, message: 'Something went wrong. This error has been logged and will be addressed by our staff. We apologize for this inconvenience!' });
                                  } else {
                                      // Check if user is in database
                                      if (!user) {
                                          res.json({ success: false, message: 'No user found' }); // Return error
                                      } else {

                                            if (Array.isArray(newTest1)) {
                ------> this does not work   user.test1[0].comments.push(newTest1);
                                            //user.test1.splice(index, 0, newTest1)
                                          } else {
               ---> this works              var testet1 = { test: newTest1.split(" "), comments: Array };
                                            user.test1.push(testet1); // Assign new name to user in database
                                          }
                                          // Save changes
                                              user.save(function(err) {
                                                  if (err) {
                                                      console.log(err); // Log any errors to the console
                                                  } else {
                                                      res.json({ success: true, message: 'Name has been updated!' }); // Return success message
                                                  }
                                              });
                                      }
                                  }
                              });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to make some tweaks at your Schema to make test1 array include objects with properties `answers` and `comments` and make them array too. And then insert it to your main Schema like this:

```
var nestedSchema = new Schema ({
  answers: {type: Array, required: false},
  comments: {type: Array, required: false}
})

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    test1: { type: [nestedSchema], required: false },
    test2: { type: Array, required: false },
    test3: { type: Array, required: false }
});
```

Then `user.test1[0].comments.push(newTest1)` should work correctly. Don't forget to pass the index of the needed answer when pushing new comment. Like this `user.test1[index].comments.push(newTest1)`

Answer (score 0):

Javascript arrays are always numbered indexes, and does not support named indexes. Unless I missed something it looks like you are trying to create an associative array by giving it a named index which will not work.

Comment: Hmm, okay. How would you go by adding the comments ?